# <input> tag gets stripped when editing a page in Plone WYSIWYG editor

Tags: plone

Despite being listed in /portal_transforms/safe_html under valid_tags with a value of "1" when I try to add an `<input>` it is stripped from the saved version of my page.

I have tried adding 'input' to the HTML Filter settings, under custom, but the change does not get saved.

'input' is not listed under nasty or stripped tags.

Why is it being removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try disabling safe_html altogether:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms/wysiwyg.html#disabling-safe-html-transformation

If that doesn't help then you have an issue with the TinyMCE editor. Usually this means that you are out of the luck and only using "Edit without visual editor" link below the text area allows you enter your HTML code.

Comment: That worked. I noticed my default editor is set to Kupu, and than when I change it to tinyMCE, it still uses Kupu... this may be part of the problem.

Comment: You can change your user specific default editor setting in your user profile.